# how to check if xml file has more than one child values using php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i have xml file `$file.xml` which includes the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<names><name>name1</name><name>name2</name><name>name3</name></names>
```

i need a way to check if `<names>` has more than one child `<name>` meaning that if the file has more than `<name>name1</name>` whick means that if `<name>name2</name>` or more exist to call a function.

i have tried the following

```
    $file = "file.xml";

    $result = file_get_contents($file);

    if(@count(file($result)) > 1) {

    //perform a function
    }
```

the `file_get_contents` already gave me the values `name1` `name2` and `name3`

but the `if(@count(file($result)) > 1) {` did nothing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its quite possible, you could use xpath in conjunction with this case:

```
$file = "file.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$names = $xml->xpath('/names/name');
if(count($names) > 1) {
    //perform a function
    echo 'perform!';
}
```

Or an alternative with `DOMDocument` with xpath as well:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($file);

$count = $xpath->evaluate('count(/names/name)');
if($count > 1) {
    echo 'perform!';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i used option 1 unless you suggest that option 2 is better
sorry i cannot vote :)

Comment: @guestofhonor77 sure no prob, both of them are good. im glad this helped